# Concatenate text with variable in variable?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create small sections of HTML code with a loop. In the loop I want to take each text value of `$start_intro_headline_X` in the simplified code below. How can I solve this?

```
$start_intro_headline_0 = "This is the first headline";
$start_intro_headline_1 = "This is the second headline";

$intro_sections ="";

for ($x = 0; $x <= 4; $x++) {
$intro_sections .= "<h2>{$start_intro_headline_{$x}}</h2>"; <-- THIS LINE IS THE PROBLEM!
} 

$pageContent = <<<EOD
$intro_sections
EOD;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the name of the variable as a string to another variable and then use it as a variable variable. I know it sounds confusing, so just see the code :) Here's the code explanation:

```
$start_intro_headline_0 = "This is the first headline";
$start_intro_headline_1 = "This is the second headline";

$intro_sections ="";

for ($x = 0; $x <= 1; $x++) {
  $var = 'start_intro_headline_'.$x;
  $intro_sections .= "<h2>{$$var}</h2>"; // Note that it's $$var, not $var
} 

echo $intro_sections;
```

The `echo` will produce `<h2>This is the first headline</h2><h2>This is the second headline</h2>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I get 'start_intro_headline_0' not 'This is the....' Is '$$var' a misspelling?

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4a84d03c0a4735d205162d13737ce701f89e71f1 --- It's working perfectly, hit Execute button and see for yourself.

Comment: Yes it's working! I thought the $$ was wrong. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Although I think the other answer works, it will be safer to avoid dynamic variables. Use an array to save your values instead:

```
$start_intro_headline = [
  "This is the first headline",
  "This is the second headline"
];

$intro_sections ="";
$total = count($start_intro_headline);
for ($x = 0; $x < $total; $x++) {
  $intro_sections .= "<h2>{$start_intro_headline[$x]}</h2>";
} 

echo $intro_sections;
```

This way you don't have to create new variables in the future, only add new values to the array. Here is an example of [how it may go wrong to use dynamic variables](https://idiallo.com/blog/one-of-the-reasons-people-hate-php).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, arrays are safer than dynamic variables. On the other hand you can never say how and what OP wants/needs to use.